# What's the correct way to remove WindowsApps\MutableBackup folder?

Tags: windows-10

The WindowsApps\MutableBackup folder stores app backups and can grow quite large.

However, there seems to be no way to empty this folder without taking ownership of the entire WindowsApps folder, a process which may break the Windows store.

Did Microsoft intend a ~correct way of getting rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Run the program 7zip as admin. 
Browse to the MutableBackup folder and delete everything inside.
No idea what Microsofts logic is with this.

Comment: Strangely enough this actually works. Though a way that's less black magick'd be preferable

Answer (score 0):

I found something online where you take ownership of WindowsApps folder, do what you want with it - deleting etc., then just go back and change ownership back to TrustedInstaller.  The way to turn it back to TrustedInstaller is this https://www.windowscentral.com/how-restore-trustedinstaller-owner-system-files-windows-10.  Once TrustedInstaller is back in charge, you still have full permissions since you were the previous owner.  Worked for me.  I make no claims as to whether this will cause issues in the Microsoft store for anybody in the future.